# Sitecore permissions within Security Disabler

Tags: security, permissions, sitecore, workflow

If you are running code using the security disabler, is it possible to re-enable security while still in the Using SecurityDisabler?

My problem is I need to test a user's permission but if you are in the SecurityDisabler and use the UserSwitcher to test permissions. It always says they have permissions. So I was hoping to re-enable security to test.

One more piece is that the code is executed when a item enters a workbox and Sitecore seems to run all of that code automatically with the Disabler which makes sense but makes it hard to test permissions.

This is on Sitecore 6.4.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `SecurityStateSwitcher` inside the `using SecurityDisabler scope`, e.g.:

```cs
Item item = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("/sitecore/system");

var canAnonymousRead = item.Security.CanWrite(Sitecore.Context.User); // returns false

using (new SecurityDisabler())
{
    canAnonymousRead = item.Security.CanWrite(Sitecore.Context.User); // returns true

    using (new SecurityStateSwitcher(SecurityState.Enabled))
    {
        canAnonymousRead = item.Security.CanWrite(Sitecore.Context.User); // returns false again
    }
}
```

`SecurityStateSwitcher` is a base class of `SecurityDisabler` (see below) so what you see above is a method for "resetting" security checks back to `Enabled` mode.

```cs
public class SecurityDisabler : SecurityStateSwitcher
{
    public SecurityDisabler : base (SecurityState.Disabled) {}
}
```